# Joining 2 tables ON a column with some missing entries

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider these 2 tables:

**CustAddress**

```
Name             Address
----             -------
John             116 States Ave
Mike             404 16th Street
```

**CustPhone**

```
Name             Phone
----             -------
John             342-345-456
Smith             678-435-567
```

How do I combine these into a single result like this in Oracle:

Customer info with Address and Phone:

```
Name             Phone               Address
----             -------             -------
John             342-345-456         116 States Ave
Smith            678-435-567
Mike                                 404 16th Street
```

Full Outer Join doesn't help as I end up losing some data.

Here is a SQL Fiddle to play with:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebb9b/1

Comment: This is Oracle.

Comment: FYI your fiddle is mySQL 5.6, not Oracle

Comment: ?? What information are you losing with a full outer join? This is exactly what full outer join was invented for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `full join`.

```
select coalesce(ca.name,cp.name) as name, cp.phone, ca.address
from custaddress ca
full join custphone cp on ca.name=cp.name
```

Or using `union all` assuming there is at most one record per name in either of the tables.

```
select name,max(phone) as phone,max(address) as address
from (select name,phone,null as address from custphone
      union all
      select name,null,address from custaddress
     ) x
group by name
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked like a charm vkp, thanks. Didn't bother looking into the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda ugly but

```
select Names.Name, CustAddress.Address, CustPhone.Phone from
(select Name from CustAddress union select Name from CustPhone) as Names
left join CustAddress on Names.Name = CustAddress.Name
left join CustPhone on Names.Name = CustPhone.Name;
```